# change Id in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My friend wants me to send him the post method given in this structure:

```
{
    "PointList" :
    [{
        "Name": "Name",
        "X": 0.5,
        "Y": 0.8,
        "RouteId": 1,
        "Description":"ds"
    }],
}
```

there is a problem every name is changed except RouteId, do I have to have any rights so that I can change it?

Comment: Are you asking you can change the property names?

Comment: no, I want to change the key

Comment: Well without knowing what exactly the `RouteId` property represents, or what the database schema is like it's hard for us to say. Wouldn't this be a better question for the friend who's dealing with the data?